# Which of the following compounds is NOT an isomer?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

[image]

Which of the following compunds is not an isomer? I cant figure out how the answer is d

Comment: Labas.  Not sure if this is *the* answer, yet one might argue a double bond in the chain (a, c, e) or a ring closure (b) were equivalent as *one* unsaturation, which is absent in d.  (In this perspective, benzene would formally yield four DBE, one by cyclicity and three by the three double bond drawn.)

Answer (score 2):

The simple way would be to count to the number of each type of atom in each molecule. Alternatively, you could also note that only d has 1 [degree of unsaturation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_unsaturation), while all the rest have 2.

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean by count to the number? like determening S and R configurations?

Comment: To quote "For a compound with formula $\ce{C_aH_bN_cO_dX_e}$ where X is F, Cl, Br or I, the degree of unsaturation is given by: degree of unsaturation = 1/2 (2 + 2a - b + c - e).  Hence 2 for $\ce{C5H9NO}$.  source: https://scilearn.sydney.edu.au/fychemistry/calculators/degree_of_unsaturation.shtml

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the simplest way is to find the molecular formula of each structure. Then, you'd see why (d) is the correct answer (isomers must have same molecular formula).